# “cracking the coding interview(fifth edition)”: 9.10 box stacking

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

> You have a stack of n boxes, with widths wi, heights hi, and depths
>   di. The boxes cannot be rotated and can only be stacked on top of one
>   another if each box in the stack larger than or equal to the box above
>   it in width, height, and depth. Implement a method to build the
>   tallest stack possible, where the height of a stack is the sum of the
>   heights of each box.

I know there are a couple of articles to talk about using dynamic programming to solve it. Since I'd like to do practice in writing recursion code, I wrote the following code:

```
const int not_possible = 999999;

class box{
public:
    int width;
    int depth;
    int height;
    box(int h=not_possible, int d=not_possible, int w=not_possible):
        width(w), depth(d), height(h) {}
};


bool check_legal(box lower, box upper){
    return (upper.depth<lower.depth) && 
           (upper.height<lower.height) &&
           (upper.width<lower.width);
}

void highest_stack(const vector<box>& boxes, bool* used, box cur_level, int num_boxes, int height, int& max_height)
{
    if(boxes.empty())
        return;

    bool no_suitable = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_boxes; ++i){
        box cur;
        if(!(*(used+i)) && check_legal(cur_level, boxes[i])){
            no_suitable = false;
            cur = boxes[i];
            *(used+i) = true;
            highest_stack(boxes, used, cur, num_boxes, height+cur.height, max_height);
            *(used+i) = false;

                    no_suitable = true;
        }
    }

    if(no_suitable){
        cout << height << endl; //for debug
        if(height > max_height)
            max_height = height;
            return;
    }
}
```

I've tested it using a lot of examples. For example:

```
boxes.push_back(box(4,12,32));
boxes.push_back(box(1,2,3));
boxes.push_back(box(2,5,6));
highest_stack(boxes, used, cur, boxes.size(), 0, max_height);
```

In the function `highest_stack`, there is one line `cout << height << endl;` for output. If I comment `no_suitable = true;`

> the output is: 1 2 4; 1 2; 1, 1 4;

if I don't comment `no_suitable = true;`

> the output is: 1 2 4; 2 4; 4; 1 2; 2; 1; 1 4; 0

Both of them can give the correct result which is 7.

> ```
> My question is:
> (1) Can anyone help me verify my solution?
> (2) Is there any more elegant recursive code for this problem?
> ```
>
> I don't think  my code is elegant.
>       Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make a directed graph where the nodes are boxes and the edges go from a box to a box that can be put on top of it.  Then I'd use use the [longest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Weighted_directed_acyclic_graphs) to find the solution.

Comment: There's a wrinkle in this problem:  Two identical boxes, per the strict reading of the problem, can be stacked on each other, which would result in a cyclic graph.  You'd need to be aware of this and handle them specially, or perhaps give the boxes names and break ties lexicographically, or some such.

Comment: @Novak if possible, can you write a recursive algorithm for this problem. I'm practicing how to write recursive algorithm. I bet I can learn a lot of stuff from your code. :-). Thanks

Comment: @Keith Randall if possible, can you write a recursive algorithm for this problem. I'm practicing how to write recursive algorithm. I bet I can learn a lot of stuff from your code. :-). Thanks

Comment: It's just Dijkstra's algorithm on a DAG with negative edgeweights.  You can find examples of Dijkstra everywhere.

Comment: @Novak the problem in the 5th edition says "a box can be stacked on top of a box *strictly* larger than it" so there are no cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Design the relation as a Set array of boxes.(Set[]) i.e. each position has a array of boxes.

Initialize each box with an index.

For each box check boxes that can be placed above the current box(box[i]) add it to the set in the set array i.e. set[i].add(box)

Run DFS with the boxes that can be placed above (the role of adjacent)

Maintain a marked[], count[] and boxTo[] arrays of boxes.

Go over the count array and find the largest value.

Traverse the way to the bottom box using the boxTo[] array.